# How do I fake dropped packets (or actually make them fail)?

Tags: tcpip, packets

**Background**

One of our clients suffers from an intermittant problem with their internet where it will drop packets when a user downloads a large file (their IT is looking into the problem).

I have an application consisting of a Web Server running Windows 2008 R2 IIS7.5, and a client running Windows 7, Chrome  which uses a long running XMlHttpRequest to transfer "messages" from the server to the client.

**The problem.**

My application should be should be fairly immune to these packet losses, but in practice it isn't.

I want to test the application under various different network problem scenarios, eg random 1 % packet loss, and bursty packet loss - say complete loss of packets for 4000 ms, and so on.

I'm looking for a solution which lets me "reproduce" a scenario and test my application. I could use 3G, or unplug and unplug the network cable, but the effects are not very reproduceable.

**The question.**

Is there an application/driver which I can install on my machine to mimick "dodgy" internet connections?  Or perhaps an appliance or proxy server I can use in the network to mock these scenarios?

I'm guessing it's not very easy to do on a modern computer because I expect most of the TCP stack is offloaded to the network card, but I would have thought this was a reasonably popular thing to try and do, however I haven't had any luck on google. I'm more proficient on Windows, but a solution which uses Linux, either as a client, or proxy would be welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple linux router in the middle could do this for you flawlessly.  Just do some reading on `netem`.  You can replicate everything including lost-packets, re-ordered packets, corrupted packets, and even latency.  I use it myself for simulating satellite based links.

Answer (score 2):

I've used TMNetSim to perform this.  It proxies whatever port you want, so it could be used for most applications.

http://www.tmurgent.com/Tools.aspx

You may want to perform a correlated packet capture on both the client and server side, and determine if the client is receivign a RST packet.  If so, is it coming from your server.  And does it occur at predictable times, such as after five minutes of inactivity.