# Windows XP procedurally drop packets

Tags: networking, windows-xp, packets

We have a need in our office network to procedurally drop incoming packets on an Windows XP machine acting as a server.

By procedurally we mean to drop a percentage of packets incoming to the XP machine from a specific IP address.

Another option is to introduce intermittent latency for an incoming IP address.

Comment: You have a need in your office to replace Windows XP (which isn't a server OS to begin with) with something more modern and not out of support. Other than that, this sounds like a development question.

Comment: The xp machine is a virtual machine. We also have a need for this to be XP. Ill ask i  the appropriate section then

Comment: You are going to have edit your question and work pretty hard to convince people that you are meeting the [professional capacity](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) requirement here. As it stands it is fast on it's way to being closed.

Comment: That is fair, I expected it wasn't the best question. I am out of the office at the moment, if you want to close it you may as well, i will revise and re-ask.

Comment: @MichaelJMulligan It appears that your question is flagged as being "not professional" enough.  There is lengthy debate on meta as to this subject.  In the effort of trying to be a valuable, and professional, contributor, I would like to suggest some changes to your question.  For starters, your situation here is weird.  Normally you would be best to perform this on a router rather than a client OS.  If you need help with that, you can see this [question](http://serverfault.com/q/389354/44519).

Comment: @MichaelJMulligan If however, there are extenuating circumstances that require you to use WinXP here, please call those out as best as you can, so people on this site can best aid you with your problem.  Alternatively, this question may be better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [WANem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) - The Wide Area Network emulator.

You can set it up as a VM with a bootable CD-rom drive.  Once booted, the web interface will let you use it as a proxy to slow down connections, drop packets, induce jitter, latency, and a number of other cool tricks.

Comment: So, create two NICs, route the xp traffic through and play.  I'll have a look.

Comment: Right. Quickest setup is to create a VM with no hard drive, 2 nics.  Set it to boot from CD.  Configure the two NICs, go to the web admin page to set your rules, then point at WANem from your test client/IP.  Pretty easy.